# React Native Java Script navigation question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I have my App.Js with an Stack Navigator (picture) and an Homescreen with an Button and I want to navigate to the Selection Screen onpress but I always get the Error the action NAVIGATE with payload name Selection was not handled by any navigator? I didn´t make any tipping errors I think. Would be great if someone can help me :) [App.js[Homescreen.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU2lw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5mbc.png)

I tried to rename everything and change the import structure but it didn`t help :/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned-up version of your code with corrected import statements and removed syntax errors:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import QuantityScreen from './Screens/QuantityScreen';
import StatisticsScreen from './Screens/StatisticsScreen';
import SelectionScreen from './Screens/SelectionScreen';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function QuantityStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Quantity" component={QuantityScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'blue',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontSize: 14,
          },
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Quantity" component={QuantityStack} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Statistics" component={StatisticsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SelectionScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```